# PLACES_API_INVALID_APP error given when trying to access Google Play Services Android

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to use Places API for Android to get Current Place. I got an API key using release SHA1 key and the correct package name. However when running the app, it gives

```
{statusCode=PLACES_API_INVALID_APP, resolution=null}
```

error and cannot get the current place details. 
Here's my code:

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build();
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                } else {
                    callPlaceDetectionApi();
                }

            }

private void callPlaceDetectionApi() throws SecurityException {
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            final CharSequence thirdPartyAttributions =
                    likelyPlaces.getAttributions();
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Place '%s' with " +
                                "likelihood: %g",
                        placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                        placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
            }
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
}
```

Any help on solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115337/places-api-invalid-app-error-from-android-play-places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated a new key without using the SHA1 release key and used it, and this solved the issue.