# Failures in "Pre-Launch report" in Google Play Developer Console in Google VR startup

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-vr

I've been working on a game using Google VR in Unity3d and I recently updated my version of unity3d and the (built in) Google VR SDK to the latest version. After doing so the pre-launch report (automated testing on firebase) is showing crashes, during the unity splash screen, on 5 out of 6 devices.

This is the issue that is reported:

```
Issue: Crash of app uk.co.softkitty.puzzleroom running instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
```

Not very helpful, it looks like a generic unit test result if the app closes unexpectedly . I've looked through the logs and cant find anything unusual from my app or unity, but I did find something. It looks to me like this may be being caused by the test script itself:

```
10-27 01:54:54.494: I/ViewInteraction(19677): Performing 'single click' action on view (with class name: is "android.widget.ImageButton" and with id: uk.co.softkitty.puzzleroom:id/ui_back_button ...............
```

This to me, looks like the test runner is exploring the app UI and the first thing it does is click the "back" button. Which I would expect to close the app. I also tried using Firebase directly, which seemed to confirm it:

[Firebase Activity Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMSvL.png)

Does that seem likely that this is just a bug/red herring caused by changes to unity/GVR Or even firebase? Has anyone else experienced this?

I just don't want to release it if it really is crashing on so many devices!

Many Thanks

Comment: I also have the problem.  I see a lot of exceptions within the device that they are using but almost nothing related to my app.

Comment: Did you figure anything out? I just got `ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}`

Comment: Same here. Nothing related to my app. I have this errors on 2 apps but only on 2 devices: Sony Xperia XZ Premium (G8142) - Android 7.1 & Samsung Galaxy J1 Ace (j1acevelte) - Android 5.1

Comment: So far everyone who has tried it says it works so it looks like an issue with the test process. But still I still haven't been able to rule out something in my code.

Comment: Exactly the same for me, from the 27 of October

Comment: Same here, I was debugging for hours, until I found out it's not even related to my app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I asked Google Play Support about this and they got back to me.

They have confirmed that the issue is caused by a new crawler used by the Pre-Launch report. Details can be found [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270) under the section "Pre-launch report versions"

They've escalated the issue and have also provided a workaround:

1. Sign in to your Play Console.
2. Select an app.
3. Select Release management > Pre-launch report > Settings.
4. In the “Pre-launch report version” section, move the Opt-out switch
   to the right until it turns blue.

I haven't verified this yet but will mark as answer once I have.

**Edit**

I have tested this and all the tests pass again so this looks like a good solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

We got this when uploading our APK as well. It started October 27th and crashed the following 4 days until we changed our setup. I couldn't see anything in our code base that should trigger this problem, so I wonder if it's related to changes on Google's side.

However, we did just did two changes and now everything's working again.

**We added the following line to `proguard-project.txt`:**

```
-keep class android.arch.** { *; }
```

I assume this was what fixed it.

At the same time we changed the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 27 (and correspondingly all belonging support libs). For all I know they could have fixed it here too..

#### Edit:

To more directly answer your question: Yes, it does seem likely that this is just a bug/red herring, not on Unity's side, but in Firebase Test Lab or in Google's support lib. I tested the APK that failed the pre-launch tests and it worked just fine on my device.

Comment: Thanks Roy, will try this later and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: This doesn't really fix the issue for me. Trying the suggestion on the other answer next time,  the one about the "pre-launch report version".